# IntelliJ html autocompleate with braces and not with quotation marks

Tags: html, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ when I edit a HTML file and write in a tag the following:

```
style=
```

then it will be autocompleated with

```
style={}
```

But I need normal HTML syntac, so `style=""` or `style=''`. In the settings -> editor -> code style -> html the `generated quote marks` stand on `single`.

What configuration am I missing?

thanks a lot.
greetings

Answer (score 0):

Please try the most recent [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) - the issue should be fixed there (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28689#comment=27-2429143)